# DLL Error when executing python using tensorflow-gpu from Matlab

Tags: python, matlab, tensorflow

I have some python code using tensorflow-gpu. In fact, only using

```py
import tensorflow as tf
```

shows the following strange behaviour:

Activating the conda environment and runnig this code in cmd works just fine. But when I run it from Matlab with the command

```matlab
!activate env_name & cd path_to_main & python main.py
```

the following error occurs:

```
Traceback (most recent call last): 
  File "D:\Programs\Anaconda3\envs\env_name\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 58, in <module> 
    from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import * 
  File "D:\Programs\Anaconda3\envs\env_name\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 28, in <module> 
    _pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper() 
  File "D:\Programs\Anaconda3\envs\env_name\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 24, in swig_import_helper 
    _mod = imp.load_module('_pywrap_tensorflow_internal', fp, pathname, description) 
  File "D:\Programs\Anaconda3\envs\env_name\lib\imp.py", line 243, in load_module 
    return load_dynamic(name, filename, file) 
  File "D:\Programs\Anaconda3\envs\env_name\lib\imp.py", line 343, in load_dynamic 
    return _load(spec) 
ImportError: DLL load failed: Die angegebene Prozedur wurde nicht gefunden. 

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred: 

Traceback (most recent call last): 
  File "main.py", line 1, in <module> 
    import tensorflow as tf 
  File "D:\Programs\Anaconda3\envs\env_name\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\__init__.py", line 28, in <module> 
    from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow  # pylint: disable=unused-import 
  File "D:\Programs\Anaconda3\envs\env_name\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\__init__.py", line 49, in <module> 
    from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow 
  File "D:\Programs\Anaconda3\envs\env_name\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 74, in <module> 
    raise ImportError(msg) 
ImportError: Traceback (most recent call last): 
  File "D:\Programs\Anaconda3\envs\env_name\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 58, in <module> 
    from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import * 
  File "D:\Programs\Anaconda3\envs\env_name\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 28, in <module> 
    _pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper() 
  File "D:\Programs\Anaconda3\envs\env_name\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 24, in swig_import_helper 
    _mod = imp.load_module('_pywrap_tensorflow_internal', fp, pathname, description) 
  File "D:\Programs\Anaconda3\envs\env_name\lib\imp.py", line 243, in load_module 
    return load_dynamic(name, filename, file) 
  File "D:\Programs\Anaconda3\envs\env_name\lib\imp.py", line 343, in load_dynamic 
    return _load(spec) 
ImportError: DLL load failed: Die angegebene Prozedur wurde nicht gefunden. 


Failed to load the native TensorFlow runtime. 

See https://www.tensorflow.org/install/errors 

for some common reasons and solutions.  Include the entire stack trace 
above this error message when asking for help.
```

Anyone knows, why this could happen and how to fix it? The link shown in the error message doesn't really help, as this error normally seems to occur when different soft/hardware components weren't installed correctly, but the fact that my code runs from cmd shows, that this is not the case here.

My System is Windows 10 with a GTX1050Ti, using CUDA10.0, cudnn 7.6.2 and tf-gpu 1.13.1 (but other verions I have tested show the same behaviour)
Matlab R2018b

Comment: See if [this](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/325435-python-api-setup-environments-how-to-get-matlab-to-use-other-env-as-interpeter) helps.

Comment: Unfortunately not. Note, that I am not using the python functions in Matlab itself, but with the ! command, I start a cmd which executes the python stuff. The activation of the environment also works - if not, tensorflow wouldn't be found at all.